# How to execute asynchronous functions in a loop using Q.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q

I need to execute an asynchronous function inside a loop (with different parameters). Any ideas how it can be done using Q module in Node.js.
Below is an example:-

```
function addAsync(a, b) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    // Wait 2 seconds and then add a + b
    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(a + b);
    }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Q.all can be used(), but that runs all in parallel. I essentially need to execute them sequentially due to a project requirement.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have to stick with Q.js I advise you to have a look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

[Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) is a popular asynchronous flow-control library that offers a wast amount of useful functions, including such functions as [series](https://github.com/caolan/async#series) or [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) that does exactly what you need. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options, but this should get you moving:

```
parameters.reduce(function (results, parameters) {
    return results.then(function () {
        return addAsync(parameters[0], parameters[1])
        .then(function (result) {
            results.push(result);
            return results;
        })
    });
}, Q([]))
.then(function (results) {
    // ...
})
.done()
```

I have a more enjoyable solutions coming in Q-IO https://github.com/kriskowal/q-io/pull/57

```
Reader(parameters)
.map(function (parameters) {
    return addAsync(parameters[0], parameters[1])
}, null, 1)
.all()
.then(function (results) {
    // ...
})
```

Where `1` is a parallelism limiter.